# change the rotation in tikz 3d?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,tdplot_main_coords]


    \coordinate (O) at (1,1,1);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}

    \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Py)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (Py)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=pink,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Py)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- cycle;

 \tdplotsetmaincoords{10}{10}%%%%%%%%%%%%this is not changing the rotation since the begin tikzpicture has alread used it once

 \coordinate (M) at (3,2,1);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}

    \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Py)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (Py)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=pink,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Py)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- cycle;
\end{document}
```

I want both cubes to have different orientations as well as be in the same figure?
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

## Remarks

You can use `scope` to have several coordinate systems in one drawing.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
        \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}
        \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Py)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (Py)$) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=pink,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Py)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    \tdplotsetmaincoords{10}{10}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,xshift=1cm]
        \coordinate (M) at (0,0,0);
        \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}
        \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Py)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (Py)$) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=pink,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Py)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]